# How to make it so the RHS of || isn't compiled for certain situations?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I have some logic that looks like this:

```
if (x > y || eval(x, y)) {
  // do something
}
```

I don't want `eval(x, y)` (this is a boolean function) to be compiled when some condition (known at compile time is met) is met (in this case we can just get rid of the `||` too, or for uniformity, we could just have `eval(x, y)` replaced with `false`).

Is there a way to achieve this?

I think one way to do this is

```
bool rhs = false;
if constexpr ( condition ) {
  rhs = eval(x, y);
}
if (x > y || rhs) {
  // do something
}
```

but then I lose the benefit of short circuiting here. I don't want to call `eval(x, y)` until `x > y` is false.

Comment: you may be looking for `define` or a more modern alternative

Comment: Where's the condition? Why do you need it not to be compiled?

Comment: Compile with optimization enabled; if the *compiler* can prove at compile time that `x>y` is always true, it should do dead code elimination of the short-circuited part.  (If you know it but the compiler doesn't, you could replace it with `if(true)` or use something like clang's `__builtin_assume(x>y);` (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-assume) or GNU C `if( !(x>y)) __builtin_unreachable();` )  (edit: I thought you were talking about `x>y` being known at compile time, not some other condition you didn't mention.  NVM.)

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it with lambda

```
auto maybe_eval = [](auto x, auto y) {
  if constexpr (some condition) 
    return false;
  else 
    return eval(x, y)
};

if (x > y || maybe_eval(x, y)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Oh I think this works. Is there any runtime cost to construct the lambda?

Comment: @roulette01: Not with optimization enabled.  It just inlines, you're not passing it around or taking a reference to the lambda.

Comment: Can you do the same thing with `if (x>y || !(!some_condition && !eval(x,y)))` or similar to short-circuit evaluation?  I probably have the exact boolean logic wrong, and it of course makes it hard to read, but the fact that the condition is known at compile time is something the compile will take advantage of for you, and do dead-code elimination.

Comment: This is actually inspired by an earlier post I saw posted on here, but I do remember in the past, I've came across situations where I don't actually want the `eval(x, y)` to be compiled for whatever reason (I can't think of a good reason at the moment, but it was a compile time issue and not a runtime issue)

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation does not work when some_condition makes `eval(x,y)` ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

Short-circuit eval of `false && eval(x,y)` will make that call into dead code.
康桓瑋 points out that short-circuit evaluation does not work when some_condition makes `eval(x,y)` ill-formed; in that case see their answer for a lambda.  In this answer, it still has to be *able* to compile, but it compiles to no asm.

```
void foo(int x, int y) {
    if (x>y || (condition && eval(x,y))) {
        sink = 1;   // store to a volatile global is easy to see in compiler asm output
    }
}
```

- With `condition = false`, it's the same as `if(x>y || false)`, i.e. `if(x>y)`.
- With `condition = true`, it's the same as `if(x>y || eval(x,y))`

Real compilers do in practice do this short-circuit eval to omit any call instruction to `eval`.  For GCC and clang at least, that dead code removal happens even with optimization disabled.  See it on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TA3cAGQImbAA5PwAjbFIQCwAOcgAHdCViFyYvX38DVPTnIRCwyLYYuMT7bEdCphEiFlIibL8AniqazPrGomKI6Nj4pKUGppbc9pGevtLyoYBKe3QfUlROLinnVABqDCYR7HVk0m2o9G9doUJa7bMAZgARbZoJFXubLQBBMy%2BAN28WM5GNtQkRtukmABrd4/T4AfThgKIpAIUR8RGwCKgexG83msNB22wvwkEFB5BBwnxdw%2B3z%2B6AImHBBDYyUYZOE23UFMJAE98QB2WnbEUgmjbCDqW53XDbXm3AUeMyKokk%2BiSin8%2BYK4WivUQyHSp48GFfPXKh6wi1W%2BmM57nDlg7mUsH8nWwvUEcWS%2B64eXKpUqiB7a6ZW4WABslgjqtJ3K12uVur1IoNRu2JppHtF1q%2Bubpn3%2BdqijUdXJ5nLdSezIrOF1ISCU6Ze9DeWbNoq9l32GKOJwg3dDQm2iaFNdFDab9yexLjmupVlFAHol9sAO7EJDbBFIlFojFY4NCXHasjbZIrbAU1BGEy7YzbdDJZxsAgAL2wILBoPQ2yISE/JQkDIMFUAIVYfGIbAmQAJQACREcd809b0pV9OUFUDDxtknUdk1FNNpwzU1PnNAVLTzcjYS4RZ6G4ABWfgAi4HRyHQbglWsWxwWWVZP0sO4%2BHIIhtBoxZIRAeieAAOh4BII3orRpEjAUAE4EgsO4kjorhpH4NhJK0chmNY9iuH4JQQCMkSWJo8g4FgFAMFZBhYkoahnOSVy4hvYxgB4O4tHaOh6AxUhLIgKJRPIKJQkaXluCE5yOGEAB5Jh6AS2zyBwNg/MkbLCFIbAnAIX5sEs7LDhK9F1iE0Fqmi%2BhUVIeKvBwaLkRZRK7JoIxgCUAA1AhsDXVLkmYHq5GEMQJE4GRpsUFQNGi/QLEMPy0FsWxDFRSzIEWJ9akqgBaVK7hFE6RkwadgCYHxtusHgBQs6oStqNwmE8bxWkCL6ZgGOJ2nyDIhHGNoUjSUGmABspBkmN7SqEboxh%2BiYOnerpRl6UJ%2BjhoH7Gx8GDCmJpYbmHhFiUXi1gMZFsDquydMY4zorM9R5JOiNpF2W9gAzO5pK0WSJU4mxrApfBiDPAT2m2LwXMYE4BIseZ%2BBsnQ8XIACWBwOIIFo7g9PIAzFNZ7KzIsqzhNErWJMU6S7ik%2Bj6IjDSguU1S7kMbg7iYtnuHV237MQBzkDQdBFbcqgjyjuJ/J4daQrCiKouy2LWFILKksjlKiHSzLoty/L1lYorMfKyrWOq1BaqmhqdNY5qolarP2tL9WUQM3hev6oaRrGibmKEwQZvESQFtHpa1E0bL9HaPmtq4iXm/2g22OfTJTvO7YrqIG7Hjuh7l6sZ7Xs6VwIHcYn2mCXHZnhyGCkyG%2Bn%2Bh8nH4cTHkaJtGIa/pGdRsYfwJqTZof8SbAPvoDKQVMabzWEsVRmhsuAsxMvwdmnNubbGAKgHYPAZIWFFo9Ow2wpYkGVppOWCsvJK3DIJNWNtbJax1nrag4kQDSFUtJbmCRpDSEEmpBI9EBRaG0kbfSIABQWGkvJCMicBT0QSIJMR0jzamUDvYa2Gs7JhwgCgZYRALxEHclfa4ZBGQGCnrNCesgp7KBnqtAwa5WrJB6igtBAcuCpXRMYx84oOYRi5jzXB%2BDCGi0jrQ2I9DKZB2YYsVhgx146WNgZCwApZJ3C0tI6QPA3aqUTkkdBbFNGWWsrbDhXCeHSD4QI566kRFiJ9lwP26iMGaJ0VrHSFh/YWw6RU8g5VwqZE4UAA) with GCC and clang.  With `condition = true`, this function compiles to the same asm as the simple original using `if (x > y || eval(x, y))`.  With `condition = false` it simplifies it to *only* check the `x > y` condition, as if `eval` always returned 0.

Fun fact: with `__attribute__((const)) int eval(int, int);` or `pure`, clang will even optimize your `if constexpr` attempt into the same asm, since it knows that the call doesn't have side effects so it's ok to not call it.